# RapberryPi quits all working applications except folders

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have raspberry pi 3 B with raspbian.

I am running some applications on the Raspberry and some of the time the Raspberry shows the lightning bolt logo (means that have some power problem).

My problem is that sometimes when I turn the screen on after I go to sleep or something, I see that all the application dont appear on screen any more (probably quit) except the folders that were open. Do you know why this is happening? Maybe it because the power problem? maybe the raspberry was in over heating?

If someone can help me, I will very appriciate it.

(sorry for the bad english...)

Comment: Look at the logs in `/var/log` for an indication on what was going on. Without that, we can't really help you. The only suggestion I can think of right now is to upgrade your power supply, just to eliminate that as a factor.

Comment: Before you upgrade your power supply, maybe you could tell us which OS you are using, raspian ?